# Append an object without merging

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have looked around but didn't exactly find what I'm looking for:
I want to append to child object values without merging.

EG:

```
const ADDRESS = {
  address1: {
    line1: 'blah 1'
    // ...
  },
  address2: {
    line1: 'blah 2'
    // ...
  },
  address3: {
    line1: 'blah3'
    // ...
  },
  address4: {
    line1: 'blah3'
    // ...
  }
}
```

If I use spread operator they get merged, I just want them appended

```
const addressesappended = {
  ...ADDRESS.address1,
  ...ADDRESS.address2
}
```

DESIRED Result:

```
{
  address1: {
    line1: 'blah 1'
    // ...
  },
  address2: {
    line1: 'blah 2'
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The desired result is not a valid object.

Comment: where is the difference of source and target?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the values only.

```js
const
    ADDRESS = { address1: { line1: 'blah 1' }, address2: { line1: 'blah 2' }, address3: { line1: 'blah3' }, address4: { line1: 'blah3' } };
    result = Object.values(ADDRESS);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the whole object using

```
const result = Object.assign({}, ADDRESS);
```

you can manually assign the child objects if matches "address"

```
let result = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(ADDRESS)) {
    if(key.includes("address")) result[key] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare the keys for the associated spread data in the target object.

```js
const addresses = {
  address1: { line1: 'blah 1' },
  address2: { line1: 'blah 2' },
  address3: { line1: 'blah3' },
  address4: { line1: 'blah3' }
};

const addressesAppended = {
  address1: { ...addresses.address1 },
  address2: { ...addresses.address2 }
};

console.log(addressesAppended);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I was looking for :)
Thanks for all your contributions